# Damaged SD card, chkdsk not working

Tags: sd-card

MY SD card is damaged and not formatting. I tried chkdsk fix but its not working, have a look

```
C:\Users\subhn>chkdsk g: /f
The type of the file system is FAT32.
Volume Serial Number is EC22-1DA0
Windows is verifying files and folders...
The \torrent\Bu77y Sch07a4sh1p Ed1t10n.iso entry contains a nonvalid link.
The size of the \torrent\Bu77y Sch07a4sh1p Ed1t10n.iso entry is not valid.
25 percent completed......
C:\Users\subhn>
```

Comment: Have you tried formatting it on Windows? `chkdsk` does no formatting. And if it can't get through, formatting is the only way to repair.

Comment: "Windows is Unable to format" This is what I got while formatting it. Tried every option on formatting but no luck.

Comment: Afaid the card is dead then, and you'll need to get a new one.

Comment: I can still access the files but its work very slow. I tried to delete the data but it is not deleting. The Sd card is under warranty but I cant send SD card with personal data.

Comment: Of course it is slow, because the card is damaged. I strongly recommend you copying down your data before it's completely lost, and get a new card. Whether you want to send in the card for warranty is a different case.